# U.S. vs. Canadian English keyboard

Tags: keyboard

What is the difference between an US and a Canadian English keyboard layout? Could you give a visual comparison?

Comment: I just looked into the practical aspects, specifically keybindings for all keys and their outputs with modifiers, and there seems to be no difference. However, it seems odd to me that Apple would have the two options if there's nothing different between them, so I'm hoping someone else can shed some light on the situation. Good question!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Could you edit this. What physical keyboard layouts are you looking at (on which specific hardware) and/or what software keyboard layouts are you looking to compare?

Comment: I just installed osx captain and have two options for keyboard. Wondering what the difference.

Answer (score 12):

There's no difference except for the flag icon.  It is presumably there so that Canadians don't have to be looking at the US flag all the time to type their language.  The same holds for ABC, which is the same as US but no flag at all, for the rest of the world.

Unfortunately Apple does not document anywhere the dozens of different software keyboards/input sources which it provides.

Comment: I am happy you mention ABC as well, that would have been my next search term.

Answer (score 2):

The orginal question is for MacOS, but it may be useful for some to know that in iOS the act of using the particular keyboard while typing causes the auto-corrections and auto-suggestions to respect regional differences in spelling. Typing “color” while using Canadian English will result in a correction, while the same will happen if you type “colour” while using the US English keyboard. Likewise, the voice dictation feature will assume you want the regional spellings corresponding to your chosen input language.

Answer (score 1):

Apple documents most hardware keyboards at:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201794

It has both French Canadian as well as English

Comment: He was asking about Canadian English. That link only has Canadian French.

Comment: The poster is asking about input sources, not hardware keyboards

Comment: @TomGewecke not everyone that sees this will be asking about hardware keyboards due to the lack of detail in the question. Also, how does the comment of the OP about two choices for el cap install relate? Hard to know if this is an Apple external keyboard or a MacBook Pro or both or neither.

Comment: @bmike  There is no hardware keyboard called either US or Canadian English.  These are the names of software keyboards.  When you install MacOS you are normally asked which software keyboard you want to use, and these are two names that can be on that list.  Apple does not document the dozens of software keyboards it provides anywhere.  Any software keyboard and be used with any hardware keyboard.

Answer (score -1):

I do not really understand the question. But there are many many keyboards for the macbook (pro) and other "hardware" keyboards.
For the software keyboards: if you compare the CanadianEnglish and the US International in Keyboard Preferences, you will see that they are NOT the same for special characters, when you hold Shift+Option, for example.

Comment: The names the poster refers are clearly for the software keyboards called US and Canadian English.  He asks what the difference is, which is "none" in terms of function.  US International PC is not mentioned anywhere by the poster.  It is a layout quite different from either US or Canadian English, borrowed from Windows, which some switchers like to continue using on a Mac.

Answer (score -1):

The Canadian English keyboard has French accents when you least need them (I'm Canadian English). Here's an example that I copied from an email from someone who hasn't figured out how to fix it yet. Nov 21é18

Comment: I'm in Switzerland and find access to accents very useful as I use French and English all the time... So do my kids, who are fluent in 3 languages...

Comment: Could you explain in more detail why you think that the é in an email you got was caused by a Canadian English keyboard? It is pretty hard to make that character without intentional action to do so. On the other hand, someone typing English using a French Canadian layout by mistake would get this every time they try to type /. That is a more likely explanation of what happened.

Answer (score -1):

One crucial difference in my opinion: The cincunflex "^" character on top of the 6 are different for the two keyboards. That causes a lot of confusion and wasted time if one of the two is in a password. Let's say the password is ˆ7337ˆ
US International: ˆ7337ˆ ,
Canadian: ^7337^

Comment: You are confused about the layout names.  The question is about about the layout called "US", not the one called "US International", which is very different.  The latter uses shift 6 as a dead key to create circumflex accented characters such as âêîôû for European languages.  "US" or "ABC" does not do that, and shift 6 when using "US" or "ABC" is exactly the same as shift 6 when using "Canadian English".

Comment: True. I didn't read the question with attention. However, the information I posted might still be useful if one has the Canadian keyboard and switch the layout in the OS to US International